# Special field Record Number in crystal report gives a count of 1 in case no records are fetched

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How I'm gonna do if I want to suppress [RecordNumber] count if no data in that section (details) as picture attached :

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the section suppress formula of that field. Something like:

```
isnull({Result.OtherField}) /*suppress this field if a data field is null*/
```